# Spaces in URL creating issues in Android

Tags: android

I am downloading images from URL, but there are spaces in URL so its skipping thoses URL.
I have gone through several arcticles, which mentioned replace space with %20 or +, both the approach are not working. So what are the alternatives now.

```
    Log.i("CountryFlagThumb", VArray.get(2).replaceAll(" ", "%20")); 

    http://id8lab.net/WorldNewsApp/flags/United Arab Emirates.png
```

Thanks

Comment: what was the issue? how do you handle it? any error messages?

Comment: no images dont get downloaded, thats it.

Comment: Post the code which downloads images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't encode the entire URL, only parts of it that come from "unreliable sources".

```
String data = URLEncoder.encode("United Arab Emirates.png", "utf-8");
String url = "http://id8lab.net/WorldNewsApp/flags/" + data;
```

Answer (score 1):

You just Encode your url like

String url =Uri.encode("http://id8lab.net/WorldNewsApp/flags/United Arab Emirates.png")

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

To download image from url use the following,

```
HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet(URI.create(path) );
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpRequest);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufHttpEntity.getContent());
httpRequest.abort();
```